# TypeScript accepts non-number/string value although the expected parameter type is a number

Tags: typescript, nestjs, type-safety

I am facing an odd issue with TypeScript which I fail to understand. It could be related to my lack of knowledge as I never faced such issue in Java and it is my first (bug-fixing) steps in TypeScript / NestJS.

It seems the type safety is not guaranteed in TypeScript and I would like to know if it works as "designed" or if there is a reason for it. Here a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
  async findAll(@Query() query, @Res() res: Response) {
      ... lines omitted ...
      this.cache.getProxyCache(query.page, query.page_size);
      ... lines omitted ...
  }
```

The `query` is an object that I got from `@Query` decorator in NestJS controller.

```
  async getProxyCache(page: number = 0, pageSize: number): Promise<AxwayProxy[]> {
    console.log(`page: ${page} typeof: ${typeof page}`);
    console.log(`pageSize: ${pageSize} typeof: ${typeof pageSize}`);

    let pageSizeAdded = pageSize + 3;
    console.log(`pageSizeAdded: ${pageSizeAdded} typeof: ${typeof pageSizeAdded}`);

    let pageSizeAdded2 = Number(pageSize) + 3;
    console.log(`pageSizeAdded2: ${pageSizeAdded2} typeof: ${typeof pageSizeAdded2}`);
    ... lines omitted ...
```

The output is (watch out for `pageSizeAdded` which is the bug, `pageSizeAdded2` is calculated correctly, because I converted from `string` to `number`):

```
page: 1 typeof: string
pageSize: 4 typeof: string
pageSizeAdded: 43 typeof: string
pageSizeAdded2: 7 typeof: number
```

I am wondering that `page` and `pageSize` are type of `string` although the function parameter is declared with `number` type.

It seems TypeScript shows an error message when I try to call the function directly with string values ( e.g. `this.cache.getProxyCache('1', '2');` ) but accept a non-number value when it is passed from another object.

Did anyone faced same issue? It is a bug, known limitation? Why it is allowed?

Thanks, Christoph

Comment: Your `query` parameter seems untyped.

Comment: If your Query type has something like: `interface Query { page: any; }` then it's possible to have strings in there. As `any` is mappable to ANY other type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand that *TypeScript* will be converted to *JavaScript* before execution. So all the typing will disappear.
When you declare a function like

```
async getProxyCache(page: number = 0, pageSize: number): Promise<AxwayProxy[]>
```

you ask for *TypeScript* to check that the parameters and return type are of appropriate type. But this check is done only at transpilation (and dev, with a good IDE) time. At runtime, the types will disappear, and you can provide whatever you want, there will neither be a control nor a cast. Only the *JavaScript* part will remain:

```
async getProxyCache(page = 0, pageSize)
```

If you wonder why *TypeScript* accepted that you call your function with anything that is not a `number`, then check the type of `page` where the function is called. If it is of type `any`, then it is declared as compatible with anything. In such case, it would probably better to declare it as `unknown` which would require to check that the type is appropriate before using it.